# Is there an std::string function to append white space up until a given indentation level

Tags: c++, string, std

I amtrying to obtain the following effect:

```
This is a message            []
This is a different message  []
Short                        []
LOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOONG[]
```

Is there a way to create a string such that a given parameter always starts at a given indentation level if possible?

e.g `string(indentation level, message1, message 2)`

Comment: That's a *very specific* use case. Unlikely such a built-in function exists. You can write a free function that does that just fine.

Comment: Much easier to find the max length first and then use the `std::setw(n)` modifier from `<iomanip>`.

Comment: Without knowing how long `LOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOONG` is, you can't align `[]`.

Comment: That is why I said "if possible" I am aware that you would need to know beforhand the length of all strings in order to dynamically set the indentation length.

Comment: Is this intended for aligning output to the screen, or do you need to modify the string itself?

Comment: Once you know the length there is also an `std::string` constructor taking the length of the string and the character you want to repeat. I'm not sure whether that or the `std::setw` version is cleaner though.

Comment: What do `message1` and `message2` represent in your string constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing like that exists in the standard library (to my knowledge) but you should be able to write something achieving this pretty easily.

```
std::string IndentedString(int n, std::string message) {

    // Construct string of 'n - message.length' spaces
    std::string indent(n - message.length, ' ');

    return message + indent;
}
```